# tf.nn.embedding_lookup with float input?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, nlp, word-embedding

I would like to implement an embedding table with float inputs instead of int32 or 64b.
The reason is that instead of words like in a simple RNN, I would like to use percentages.
For example in case of a recipe; I may have 1000 or 3000 ingredients; but in every recipe I may have a maximum of 80.
The ingredients will be represented in percentage for example: ingredient1=0.2 ingredient2=0.8... etc

my problem is that tensorflow forces me to use integers for my embedding table:

> **TypeError**: Value passed to parameter ‘indices’ has DataType float32 not in list of allowed values: int32, int64

any suggestion?
I appreciate your feedback,

example of embedding look up:

```
inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, ninp], name=“x”)
n_vocab = len(int_to_vocab)
n_embedding = 200 # Number of embedding features 
with train_graph.as_default():
    embedding = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform((n_vocab, n_embedding), -1, 1))
    embed = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embedding, inputs)
```

the error is caused by

```
inputs = tf.placeholder(**tf.float32,** shape=[None, ninp], name=“x”)
```

I have thought of an algorithm that could work using loops. But, I was wondering if there is a more direct solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`tf.nn.embedding_lookup`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/embedding_lookup) can't allow float input, because the point of this function is to select the embeddings at the **specified rows**.

Example:

[image: embed-lookup]

Here there are 5 words and 5 embedding 3D vectors, and the operation returns the 3-rd row (with 0-indexing). This is equivalent to this line in tensorflow:

```
embed = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embed_matrix, [3])
```

You can't possibly look up a floating point index, such as `0.2` or `0.8`, because there is no `0.2` and `0.8` row index in the matrix. Highly recommend [this post by Chris McCormick](http://mccormickml.com/2016/04/19/word2vec-tutorial-the-skip-gram-model/) about word2vec.

What you describe sounds more like a softmax loss function, which outputs a probability distribution over the target classes.

Comment: Hi Maxim, thanks for the good explanation =)
I know that the embeeding_lookup was though to select rows. 

I wanted to use this approach to avoid unnecessary multiplications in my model. for example if I have 1000 elements where all of them are 0 except the first two I could made a smaller matrix and do a matmul between the first two elements of my input and the first two rows of the matrix. I believe I can develop this kind of logic. I was wondering if tensorflow offers something out of the box.